# Bootstrap bug on mobile. Can only replicate on live site. 100% stuck

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been working on website and my CTA Buttons look fine on computers, but on mobile they turn gradient. I can not get the gradient bug to reproduce with devtools.

I have tried everything I can think of to try and get this to reproduce. I am out of ideas.

I am new to coding, so my code is a little sloppy. Please forgive me. I have added the code to codepen here: https://codepen.io/rob-connolly/pen/JjXQJgq

live site where you can see bug on mobile: https://grobconnolly.github.io/cloverweb/

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500);
.service-5 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #636468;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.service-5 h1,
.service-5 h2,
.service-5 h3,
.service-5 h4,
.service-5 h5,
.service-5 h6 {
  color: #3e4555;
}

.service-5 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.service-5 .linking {
  color: #3e4555;
}

.service-5 .linking:hover {
  color: #316ce8;
}

.service-5 .font-weight-medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.service-5 .bg-light {
  background-color: #f4f8fa !important;
}

.service-5 .subtitle {
  color: #8d97ad;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.service-5 .card.card-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(115, 128, 157, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(115, 128, 157, 0.1);
}

.service-5 .wrap-service5-box .card-body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.service-5 .wrap-service5-box .text-success-gradiant {
  background: #f47820;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction(to right), #f47820 0%, #f47820 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#f47820), to(#f47820));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f47820 0%, #f47820 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f47820 0%, #f47820 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f47820 0%, #f47820 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.service-5 .wrap-service5-box .icon-size {
  font-size: 45px;
}

.service-5 .btn-md {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#textWhite {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.featureSection {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ourFeatures {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

* {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #636468;
}

.heroText {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #373E42;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-bottom: .3%;
}

#subHeroText {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #6b7175;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#setupText {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(107, 113, 117);
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

#heroButton {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#cancelAnytime {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(107, 113, 117);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.mainSubjects {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

.footer {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #eee !important;
  width: 100%
}

.priceText {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.secondSection {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.extraPad {
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}

.question1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.priceBox {
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #E9EEF1;
  border-style: solid;
  padding-top: 3%;
}

.dollarSymbol,
.mo,
.amount {
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}

#extraSpace {
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.dollarSymbol {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.amount {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.mo {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.faq {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#priceIcons {
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.iconFeatures {
  padding-left: 0%;
}

.iconTextPrice {
  padding-left: 3%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.iconUs {
  left: 27%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}

.textIcon {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#heroButtonPricing {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

li {
  font-size: 12px;
  justify-content: left;
}

.heroBottom {
  background-color: white;
}

.heroSection {
  background-color: #F8FBFC;
}

.liRight {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #F8FBFC;
}

li.borderless {
  border: 0 none;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.subHeroTextBottom {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(107, 113, 117);
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.mainSubjects {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

.mainSubjectsWhy {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

.mainSubjectsFaq {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-top: 8em;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

.subjectHeader {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

.readyToSignUp {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .1em;
}

.secondSubject {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.thirdTitle {
  padding-top: 15px
}

.calButton {
  padding-top: 400px;
}

.featureIconLeft1 {
  left: 10%;
}

.featureTextLeft1 {
  left: 6%;
}

.featureIconRight2 {
  left: 5%;
}

.featureTextRight2 {
  left: 1%;
}

.robpic {
  width: 200px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.sectionSpace {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
}

.backGround {
  background-color: #F8FBFC;
  width: 100%;
}

.tjFooterLogo {
  max-width: 100px
}

#noBorder {
  border: none;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  background-color: #F8FBFC;
}

.footerText {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

.fullWidth {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.footerLogo {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
}

.footerTextCopy {
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgb(107, 113, 117);
  font-size: 10px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .mainSubjects,
  .mainSubjectsWhy {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .subjectContent {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  .heroText {
    font-size: 64px;
    padding-top: 4%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
  }
  .subHeroText {
    font-size: 20px;
    word-spacing: .2em;
  }
  .btn-primary {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .mainSubjects {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  .subjectContent {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .name {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 200;
  }
  .footerLogo {
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .footerText {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:wght@200;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Clover Networks and TextJet Loyalty</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a href="./index.html" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="./assets/images/TextJet.png" height="28" alt="CoolBrand">
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">How it Works</a>
        <a href="https://support.textjet.com/en/" class="nav-item nav-link">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#pricingSection" class="nav-item nav-link">Pricing</a>

      </div>
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <a href="#pricingSection" class="nav-item nav-link">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="https://app.textjet.com/app/login" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div class="container-flex heroSection">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class='heroText text-center'>Powerful loyalty software for small businesses!
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h2 id="subHeroText">Now available on Clover Networks!
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div id="setupText">Get set-up in minutes. </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <a href="#pricingSection" id="heroButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</a>
          <div class="row">
            <div id="cancelAnytime" class="col-12 text-center">No commitment. Cancel anytime.</div>
          </div>

          <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/images/hero-image.png" alt="TextJet Hero images">
          <img class="img-fluid heroBottom" src="./assets/images/hero-bottom.png" alt="img for bottom">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container secondSection">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="mainSubjects">Powerful Loyalty</h3>
        <p class="subjectContent">Streamline your loyalty platform to maximize your reach. TextJet helps you turn occasional customers into loyal fans. We have spent countless hours designed and developing a system that will give you the upper hand over your competition. Not sure
          if TextJet is right for you... schedule a demo and find out why hundreds of businesses rely on TextJet. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/images/happy-customer1.png" alt="Happy Customer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/images/happy-customer2.png" alt="Happy Customer">

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="mainSubjects">Marketing Autopilot</h3>
        <p class="subjectContent">We know running a business can be time restraining. With TextJet Marketing Autopilot we provide a powerful marketing suite without little to no effort on your part! After you set-up your account with one of our Customer Support Representatives,
          everything will be in place for you to see results with TextJet! </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="mainSubjects">Retention Plus</h3>
        <p class="subjectContent">TextJet retention plus is a really cool tool we built to help you keep your customers coming back. Let's pretend Suzy comes into your store today, but you don't see her for 30+ days. TextJet retention starts to go to work for you. Our tools help
          entice Suzy to come back to your store. It's really an amazing tool for your business!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/images/happy-customer3.png" alt="Happy Customer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--  Features-->
  <div class="bg-light py-5 service-5 featureSection">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Row  -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <p class="mainSubjects ourFeatures">Our Features</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 wrap-service5-box">
          <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <div class="mr-4 mb-2 text-success-gradiant icon-size"><i class="far fa-comment"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <h6 class="font-weight-medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linking">Rich
                                            Messaging</a></h6>
                <p class="mt-3">Send beautiful images or videos directly to your customers' cell phones.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column -->
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 wrap-service5-box">
          <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <div class="mr-4 mb-2 text-success-gradiant icon-size"><i class="fab fa-medapps"></i>

              </div>
              <div class="">
                <h6 class="font-weight-medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linking">Retention
                                            Plus</a></h6>
                <p class="mt-3">TextJet tracks how long it's been since a customer has been to your store. We set-up triggers to bring them back to your store. </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column -->
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 wrap-service5-box">
          <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <div class="mr-4 mb-2 text-success-gradiant icon-size"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>

              </div>
              <div class="">
                <h6 class="font-weight-medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linking">Handsfree
                                            Marketing</a></h6>
                <p class="mt-3">TextJet is an easy to use marketing solution built for small businesses. It takes about 4 minutes to set-up and your account will be ready to go.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column -->
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 wrap-service5-box">
          <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <div class="mr-4 mb-2 text-success-gradiant icon-size"><i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <h6 class="font-weight-medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linking">Analytics &
                                            Tracking
                                        </a></h6>
                <p class="mt-3">We have reporting in place so you can see how your account is performing. We want you to see the value of TextJet!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column -->
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 wrap-service5-box">
          <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <div class="mr-4 mb-2 text-success-gradiant icon-size"><i class="far fa-object-group"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="">
                <h6 class="font-weight-medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linking">2-Way
                                            Messaging</a></h6>
                <p class="mt-3">You can have a 2-way conversation with your customers using TextJet. This is a great customer service tool.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column -->
        <!-- Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4 wrap-service5-box">
          <div class="card card-shadow border-0 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body d-flex">
              <div class="mr-4 mb-2 text-success-gradiant icon-size"><i class="far fa-gem"></i></div>
              <div class="">
                <h6 class="font-weight-medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="linking">SmartPulse
                                            (coming soon)</a></h6>
                <p class="mt-3">Find out how your customers feel about your store. Resolve issues and keep your customers happy</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <div id="setupText">Get set-up in minutes. </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
              <a href="#pricingSection" id="heroButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign
                                    Up</a>
              <div class="row">
                <div id="cancelAnytime" class="col-12 text-center">No commitment. Cancel anytime.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- End Features-->




  <!-- Pricing -->

  <div class="container-flex sectionSpace bg-white">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
        <a id="pricingSection"></a>
        <h1 class="mainSubjects">Pricing</h1>
        <p class="subHeroText">Our plans are designed to grow with you! No contracts, no set-up fees, and awesome customer support is included in all packages. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Starter Plan</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$1 <small class="text-muted">/
                                            mo</small></h1>
              <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4 priceText">

                <li class="priceText">Points Rewards</li>
                <li class="priceText">Custom Branding</li>
                <li class="priceText">Handsfree Markting</li>
                <li class="priceText">Fraud Protection</li>
                <li class="priceText">Promo Text Messaging</li>
                <li class="priceText">2-way Messaging</li>
                <li class="priceText">Reporting</li>
                <li class="priceText">50 SMS/ Month</li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get
                                        started</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Business Plan</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$39 <small class="text-muted">/
                                            mo</small></h1>
              <ul class="list-und mt-3 mb-4 priceText">

                <li class="priceText">Points Rewards</li>
                <li class="priceText">Custom Branding</li>
                <li class="priceText">Handsfree Markting</li>
                <li class="priceText">Fraud Protection</li>
                <li class="priceText">Promo Text Messaging</li>
                <li class="priceText">2-way Messaging</li>
                <li class="priceText">Reporting</li>
                <li class="priceText">1000 SMS/ Month</li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get
                                        started</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro Plan</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$89 <small class="text-muted">/
                                            mo</small></h1>
              <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                <li class="priceText">Points Rewards</li>
                <li class="priceText">Custom Branding</li>
                <li class="priceText">Handsfree Markting</li>
                <li class="priceText">Fraud Protection</li>
                <li class="priceText">Promo Text Messaging</li>
                <li class="priceText">2-way Messaging</li>
                <li class="priceText">Reporting</li>
                <li class="priceText">5000 SMS/ Month</li>
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get
                                        Started</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        </section>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h3 class="mainSubjects text-center">Ready to see the TextJet difference?</h4>
          <p class='subHeroText text-center'>We are here to help you grow your business!
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <div id="setupText">Get set-up in 15 minutes.
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <a href="#pricingSection" id="heroButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign
                            Up</a>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div id="cancelAnytime" class="col-12 text-center">No commitment, Cancel anytime.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="container-flex footer">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-4 text-center">
                    <img class="footerLogo" src="./assets/images/textjet_fitted.png" alt="textjet logo" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center footerText">Pricing</div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center footerText">FAQ</div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center footerText">Contact Support</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center footerText">Privacy Policy</div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center footerText">Terms of Service</div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center footerText">Anti-Spam Policy</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12 text-center footerTextCopy">
                    © Copyright 2020 Textjet LLC
                  </div>
                </div>


</body>

</html>
```

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pitOb.jpg)

[Web Version[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eotD.png)

Comment: Have you used the element inspector to see *where* this style is coming from?

Comment: I can confirm dev tools doesn't reproduce and I see the issue on mobile device

Comment: Looks fine, no client will ever notice this.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have. I have found the btn btn-success tag, i have even searched for everything with the word Gradient in css, changed the all to the orange color and I have searched for everything under @ mobile.   I am lost!

Comment: Surely the OS of the mobile you are using sets a default style to the <button> tag ... which OS and mobile are you using?

Comment: @bru17 Catalina and IOS 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less a mobile issue and more a Safari issue as I'm able to see it on desktop and mobile on macOS / iOS respectively.

The issue is `type="button"` which you've applied to your hyperlink.  In Bootstrap the following CSS is applied:

```
[type=button], [type=reset], [type=submit], button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

That is overriding elements of the `.btn` class.  Removing `type="button"` causes your hyperlink to display as expected.

Comment: This has resolved the issue Robert.  Thank you, I would've never guessed that. I really appreciate it! Cheers!